# How do I compare two columns for equality in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two columns that are joined together on certain criteria, but I would also like to check if two other columns are identical and then return a bit field if they are.

Is there a simpler solution than using CASE WHEN?

Ideally I could just use:

```
    SELECT Column1 = Column2 AS MyDesiredResult
      FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.PrimaryKey = Table2.ForeignKey
```

Comment: Return a bit field/column in the output?

Comment: Really great question, wish that syntax works.  NOTE:  In C++ and other C languages they use '=' for an assignment operation and == for comparison.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

What's wrong with CASE for this? In order to see the result, you'll need at least a byte, and that's what you get with a single character.

```
CASE WHEN COLUMN1 = COLUMN2 THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS MyDesiredResult
```

should work fine, and for all intents and purposes accomplishes the same thing as using a bit field.

Comment: I was looking for something short. CASE WHEN seems to be overly long for my taste.

Comment: I posted the actual CASE WHEN statement - how short do you need? SQL statement length differences of a few characters are meaningless, and being terse where you don't need to can make your code a lot harder to maintain later. Avoiding the proper construct to try and find one that's a few letters shorter to type is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Consider using numbers and not characters: "CASE WHEN COLUMN1 = COLUMN2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS MyDesiredResult", but I agree with Ken, this is the best choice.

Comment: @Rob: I figured Orion would know whether a 1 or a '1' would be more useful in the actual usage. :-)

Comment: When you only want to define cases of 0 or 1, I usually use a BIT explicitly. Just do like: ... then cast (1 as bit) ...

Comment: @hainstech: That works, of course. But in the case where you're simply returning data for the user to view, say in a grid of some kind, does it really matter? You may cast to a bit, but the grid is still going to need a character to display (8 bits), and unless you're returning a ++whole lot++ of bit fields, the bandwidth savings will be less than the performance hit of the cast().

Comment: I'm not trying to find some extremely terse way to say something. COLUMN1 = COLUMN2 AS ThirdColumn is sufficiently long to communicate th meaning. I find CASE WHEN for this scenario unwieldy.

Comment: I disagree. COLUMN1 = COLUMN2 AS ThirdColumn isn't nearly as undestandable to someone not familiar with the data, whereas the CASE WHEN is extremely readable and understandable. Not saying you're wrong, mind you; just that I don't agree. :-)

Comment: Returning a bit is preferable in this case because it will ensure the .Net data provider or ODBC driver will return a Boolean value, i.e. the client code will be made more explicit rather than dealing with case-sensitivity ('y', 'Y') or magic numbers (e.g. =0, >0, or >=0 means true)

Comment: This doesn't work when COLUMN1 and COLUMN2 are both NULL

Answer (score 20):

> **CASE WHEN** is the better option

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN COLUMN1 = COLUMN2 
    THEN '1' 
    ELSE '0' 
  END 
  AS MyDesiredResult
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.PrimaryKey = Table2.ForeignKey
```

Answer (score 5):

The use of IIF? And it depends on version of SQL Server.

```
SELECT
IIF(Column1 = Column2, 1, 0) AS MyDesiredResult
FROM Table;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with the `CASE WHEN` also.

Depending on what you actually want to do, there may be other options though, like using an outer join or whatever, but that doesn't seem to be what you need in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding David Elizondo's answer, this can give false positives. It also does not give zeroes where the values don't match.

### Code

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE (
    ColID   int     IDENTITY,
    Col2    int
)

DECLARE @t2 TABLE (
    ColID   int     IDENTITY,
    Col2    int
)

INSERT INTO @t1 (Col2) VALUES (123)
INSERT INTO @t1 (Col2) VALUES (234)
INSERT INTO @t1 (Col2) VALUES (456)
INSERT INTO @t1 (Col2) VALUES (1)

INSERT INTO @t2 (Col2) VALUES (123)
INSERT INTO @t2 (Col2) VALUES (345)
INSERT INTO @t2 (Col2) VALUES (456)
INSERT INTO @t2 (Col2) VALUES (2)

SELECT
    t1.Col2 AS t1Col2,
    t2.Col2 AS t2Col2,
    ISNULL(NULLIF(t1.Col2, t2.Col2), 1) AS MyDesiredResult
FROM @t1 AS t1
JOIN @t2 AS t2 ON t1.ColID = t2.ColID
```

### Results

```
     t1Col2      t2Col2 MyDesiredResult
----------- ----------- ---------------
        123         123               1
        234         345             234 <- Not a zero
        456         456               1
          1           2               1 <- Not a match
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution avoiding `CASE WHEN` is to use `COALESCE`.

```
SELECT
    t1.Col2 AS t1Col2,
    t2.Col2 AS t2Col2,
    COALESCE(NULLIF(t1.Col2, t2.Col2),NULLIF(t2.Col2, t1.Col2)) as NULL_IF_SAME
 FROM @t1 AS t1
JOIN @t2 AS t2 ON t1.ColID = t2.ColID
```

`NULL_IF_SAME` column will give `NULL` for all rows where `t1.col2 = t2.col2` (including `NULL`).
Though this is not more readable than `CASE WHEN` expression, it is ANSI SQL.

Just for the sake of fun, if one wants to have boolean bit values of 0 and 1 (though it is not very readable, hence not recommended), one can use (which works for all datatypes):

```
1/ISNULL(LEN(COALESCE(NULLIF(t1.Col2, t2.Col2),NULLIF(t2.Col2, t1.Col2)))+2,1) as BOOL_BIT_SAME.
```

Now if you have one of the numeric data types and want bits, in the above `LEN` function converts to string first which may be problematic,so instead this should work:

```
1/(CAST(ISNULL(ABS(COALESCE(NULLIF(t1.Col2, t2.Col2),NULLIF(t2.Col2, t1.Col2)))+1,0)as bit)+1) as FAST_BOOL_BIT_SAME_NUMERIC
```

Above will work for Integers without `CAST`.

NOTE: also in SQLServer 2012, we have `IIF` function.

Comment: Like you said, this is difficult to read (and maintain). It is better to tell the OP there is no simpler solution than using CASE statement. The CASE statement is also part of the ANSI standard.

Answer (score -2):

The closest approach I can think of is **NULLIF**:

```
SELECT 
    ISNULL(NULLIF(O.ShipName, C.CompanyName), 1),
    O.ShipName,      
    C.CompanyName,
    O.OrderId
FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Orders] O
INNER JOIN [Northwind].[dbo].[Customers] C
ON C.CustomerId = O.CustomerId

GO
```

**NULLIF** returns the first expression **if the two expressions are not equal**. If the expressions are equal, NULLIF returns a null value of the type of the first expression.

So, above query will return *1* for records in which that columns are equal, *the first expression* otherwise.

Comment: See my answer that begins, "Regarding David Elizondo's answer".

Comment: You are right Rob. the ISNULL function can give false positives. It should return something that differentiate completely from the context of that two columns values. In my example I'm comparing varchar columns so no problem returning value an int 1. And as I said my solution doesn't return zero (0) but it creates a differentiation when the columns are/aren't equal. It is the closest solution I can think of if he doesn't want to use CASE :)