# How to compare two columns in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two columns in SQL Server in two different tables.  One column has `9.011`, and other table columns has `9011`.  I need to remove the `.` and compare these two columns to see whether they are equal.

Can anybody help me out how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you checkhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632792/how-do-i-compare-two-columns-for-equality-in-sql-server

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL? The syntax will probably differ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN REPLACE (Table1.ColName1,'.','') = Table2.ColName2 
            THEN 'Equal' 
            ELSE 'Not Equal' 
            END AS IsEqual
    FROM Table1
    INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.PrimaryKey = Table2.ForeignKey
```

This query will return `Equal` if they are equal and `Not Equal` if they are not.

`REPLACE()` will remove `.` from `ColName1`.

Comment: I would still prefer to be explicit in this case, but that is a very nice use of implicit conversion.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that your columns are decimal type, so I have converted them to varchar first

```
where 
replace(Convert(varchar(50), column1 ),'.','') = Convert(varchar(50), column2)
```

Comment: `float` & `int`, `decimal(4,3)` & `decimal(4,0)`, `numeric(4,3)` & `numeric(4,0)` (given the numbers in question) etcetera should all be fine with this approach - so long as their scale & precision capture the digits to compare as strings of course.

Answer (score 2):

Casting the numbers as strings, cleaning up the decimal point, and comparing should work for numeric types with scale & precision to capture all the digits to compare.

For example, the following PoC in T-SQL...

```
DECLARE @foo float = 9.011;
DECLARE @bar int = 9011;
--Yup!
--DECLARE @foo decimal(4,3) = 9.011;
--DECLARE @bar decimal(4) = 9011;
----Yup!
--DECLARE @foo numeric(4,3) = 9.011;
--DECLARE @bar numeric(4) = 9011;
----Yup!
--...etcetera.

DECLARE @fooString varchar(max) = CAST(@foo AS varchar(max));
DECLARE @barString varchar(max) = CAST(@bar AS varchar(max));

PRINT '@fooString = ' + @fooString;
PRINT '@barString = ' + @barString;

IF (REPLACE(@fooString, '.', '') = @barString
    PRINT 'Yup!';
ELSE
    PRINT 'Nope....';
```

...yields the following output:

```
@fooString = 9.011
@barString = 9011
Yup!
```

No, you would not need `varchar(max)` of course: just set more reasonable string lengths for your needs.