# How to compare three column in sql

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want compare 3 column value which comparison value from **Col2** in table.

`Col1   Col2    Col3`

`12      <      25      TRUE`

`25      >      20      TRUE`

`15      =      25      FALSE`

```
SELECT (case when Col2 = '<' then  Col1 < Col3 else  Col1  end)
```

Can anyone help me ?
Advanced Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried _anything_ to solve your problem? People love to show their efforts but you need to show yours first. Do you know basic T-SQL? That doesn't sound that hard at all. First Google result is [How do I compare two columns for equality in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1632792/447156) for example..

Comment: Hi Soner, i tried more than 2 hours even i try search in google. finally i give up then only post here. here the sample..CASE WHEN col1<col2 THEN col1 ELSE col2 END

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using `case`, like this:

```
 case 
   when Col2 = '<' then
     Col1 < Col3
   when Col2 = '>' then
     Col1 > Col3
   when Col2 = '=' then
     Col1 = Col3
 end case
```

the query could be

```
 select case 
          when col2 = '=' then
            case when (col1 = col3) then 1 else 0 end
          when col2 = '>' then
            case when (col1 > col3) then 1 else 0 end
          when col2 = '<' then
            case when (col1 < col3) then 1 else 0 end
          else
            0  
        end 
   from MyTable
```

another possibily is

```
  (Col2 = '<' and (Col1 < Col3)) or
  (Col2 = '>' and (Col1 > Col3)) or
  (Col2 = '=' and (Col1 = Col3))
```

Comment: Based 1 solution i got error on after then...
Incorrect syntax near '<'. Please advise

Comment: @user3538475: if you want to put it into *sql query*, say, into `where` (not in the stored procedure) you have to either use the *second* construction or  hide boolean value (as `1` and `0` etc.)

Comment: Thank  you.. save my day..

Comment: @user3538475: You're welcome! Next time, please, add your *attempts* for us not guessing what you're looking for (stored procedure, sql etc.)

Comment: Sorry, noted . i will aware on this. Tq