# SQL: Deleting Identical Columns With Different Names

Tags: sql, duplicates, case, alter

My original table ("original_table") looks like this (contains both numeric and character variables):

```
  age height height2 gender gender2
1  18   76.1    76.1      M       M
2  19   77.0    77.0      F       F
3  20   78.1    78.1      M       M
4  21   78.2    78.2      M       M
5  22   78.8    78.8      F       F
6  23   79.7    79.7      F       F
```

I would like to remove columns from this table that have identical entries, but are named differently. In the end, this should look like this ("new_table"):

```
  age height gender
1  18   76.1      M
2  19   77.0      F
3  20   78.1      M
4  21   78.2      M
5  22   78.8      F
6  23   79.7      F
```

**My Question:** Is there a standard way to do this in SQL? I tried to do some research and came across the following link : [How do I compare two columns for equality in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632792/how-do-i-compare-two-columns-for-equality-in-sql-server/1632831)

**What I Tried So Far:** It seems that something like this might work:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table AS SELECT * FROM original_table;

ALTER TABLE new_table
ADD does_age_equal_height varchar(255);

    UPDATE new_table 

SET     does_age_equal_height =  CASE  
WHEN age = height THEN '1' ELSE '0' END AS does_age_equal_height;
```

From here, if the "sum" of all values in the "does_age_equal_height" column equals to the number of rows from "new_table" (i.e. `select count(rownum) from new_table`) - this must mean that both columns are equal, and that one of the columns can be dropped.

However, this is a very inefficient method, even for tables having a small number of columns. In my example, I have 5 columns - this means that I would have to repeat the above process " 5C2" times, i.e.  5! / (2!*3!)   = 10 times. For example:

```
ALTER TABLE employees
  ADD does_age_equal_height varchar(255),
     does_age_equal_height2 varchar(255)
does_age_equal_gender varchar(255)
does_age_equal_gender2 varchar(255)
does_height_equal_height2 varchar(255)
does_height_equal_gender varchar(255)
does_height_equal_gender2 varchar(255)
does_height2_equal_gender varchar(255)
does_height2_equal_gender2 varchar(255)
does_gender_equal_gender2 varchar(255);
```

This would then be followed by multiple CASE statements - further complicating the process.

**Can someone please show me a more efficient way of doing this?**

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused - why would you need to compare all combinations of columns?  Can't you just check the ones that are visibly duplicates (e.g. height and height2 in your example?  A cursory examination of the first few rows should be enough to identify likely candidates to check, with only 5 columns.

Comment: @ APH: thank you for your reply! In my real table there are hundreds of columns and thousands of rows . therefore I do not think a cursory examination will be possible. thank you!

Comment: for duplication of columns, you should consider multiple columns values, if I'm wrong, correct me.

Comment: @ Farshid Shekari: Thank you for your reply! I think you need to consider ALL column values? Thanks!

Comment: What if you had two columns in table with 10,000, or 1million rows and all were identical except 1 row, that means you *keep* both columns for the sake of 1 row? This seems an odd sort of situation to be in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope to get your problem in the right way. This is my code in SqlServer to handle it, you should customize it based on Netezza SQL.

**My idea is:**
*Calculate MD5 for each column and then compare these columns together, if there is the same hash, one of the columns will be chosen.*

I going to create the below table for this problem:

```
CREATE TABLE Students
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    StudentName VARCHAR (50),
    Course VARCHAR (50),
    Score INT,
    lastName VARCHAR (50) -- another alias for StudentName ,
    metric INT, -- another alias for score
    className VARCHAR(50) -- another alias for Course 
)
GO

INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('Sally', 'English', 95, 'Sally', 95, 'English');
INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('Sally', 'History', 82, 'Sally', 82, 'History');
INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('Edward', 'English', 45, 'Edward', 45, 'English');
INSERT INTO Students VALUES ('Edward', 'History', 78, 'Edward', 78, 'History');
```

after creating the table and inserting sample records, it turns to find similar columns.

step 1. Declare variables.

```
DECLARE @cols_q VARCHAR(max), 
        @cols VARCHAR(max), 
        @table_name  VARCHAR(max)= N'Students', 
        @res  NVARCHAR(max),
        @newCols VARCHAR(max),
        @finalResQuery VARCHAR(max);
```

step 2. Generate dynamics query for calculating a hash for every column.

```
SELECT @cols_q = COALESCE(@cols_q+ ', ','')+'HASHBYTES(''MD5'',  CONVERT(varbinary(max), (select '+ COLumn_NAME +' as t  from Students FOR XML AUTO))) as '+ COLumn_NAME,
        @cols = coalesce(@cols + ',','')+COLumn_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table_name; 
 set  @cols_q = 'select '+  @cols_q +' into ##tmp_'+ @table_name+' from '+ @table_name;
```

step 3. Run generated query.

```
 exec(@cols_q)
```

step 4. Get columns that duplicated columns removed.

```
  set @res = N'select  uniq_colname into ##temp_colnames
  from(
  select  max(colname) as uniq_colname from (
     select * from ##tmp_Students 
 )tt
 unpivot ( 
    md5_hash for colname in ( '+ @cols +')
 ) as tbl
 group by md5_hash
 )tr';
   exec ( @res);
```

step 5. Get final results

```
select @newCols  = COALESCE(@newCols+ ', ','')+ uniq_colname from ##temp_colnames

 set @finalResQuery = 'select '+ @newCols +' from '+ @table_name;
 exec (@finalResQuery)
```

Comment: @ Farshid Shekari : Thank you for your answer! It is a bit too advanced for me to understand at the moment, but I will try to get there someday! Thanks!